# I don't have a 'I'll enter additional info on my own' button for correcting the cost basis of a stock sale on TurboTax online

Tags: united-states, cost-basis, online-tools, turbotax

The help section of TurboTax says that to enter the corrected cost basis of a stock sale, I need to click the 'I'll enter additional info on my own' button, but I don't have this button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the option 'I'll enter one sale at a time' for the button to appear.

The button is **not** available if you select the option to enter a summary for each sale category.